# Pass a gridview column value to a session using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, gridview

I have a gridview that contains a list of products. What i am trying to do is using the ItemTemplate is pass the ProductID of the selected item using an Onclick event to a session so i can then lookup that session on another page to avoid having the ProductID shown in the URL.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GVProducts" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GVProducts_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <Columns>
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FileName"  
                    DataImageUrlFormatString="Images/{0}" HeaderText="Image">
                    <ControlStyle Height="80px" Width="80px" />
            </asp:ImageField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="ProductID" > 
<ItemTemplate> 
        <a onclick="javascript:function setSessionVariable(<%#Eval("ProductID")%>)"  href="ProductDetail.aspx"><%#Eval("Title")%></a> 
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField> 

        </Columns>
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
              <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
              <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
              <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
              <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
              <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Hopefully it is something simple as i am just starting out with javascript but i cant seem to get it to pass to the session.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call a web method from your javascript (using jQuery) and set the session on the web method:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static void SetVar(string myVar)
  {
    Session["var"] = myVar;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/SetVar",
  data: "{'myVar':'SessionVarValueSetOnJavascript'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

[See this page for a nice example](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery library in your project, you may use jQuery ajax to send data to server pages.

```
function setSessionVariable(selectedval)
{
 $.post("yourserverpage.aspx", { productId : selectedval },function(data){
    alert("set to session!");
 });    
}
```

and create an aspx page called youserverpage.aspx and read the querystring value in the page load and set to session.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Session should be done in ServerSide. Try this

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="ProductID" > 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="MyLink" runat="server" 
                  CommandName="SendID" 
                  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>'>
            <%#Eval("Title")%>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-Behind

```
   protected void GVProducts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the 
        // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked. 
        if (e.CommandName == "SendID")
        {
            // Get the ProductID stored in the CommandArgument 
            // property to an String. 
            string clickedProductID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            // Set that ProductID to Session        
            Session["ProductID"] = clickedProductID;

            // Redirect to the newpage. 
            Response.Redirect("ProductDetails.aspx");
        }
}
```

Please dont forget to add `OnRowCommand="GVProducts_RowCommand"` to the GridView markup.

---

Update:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GVProducts" runat="server" 
    OnRowCommand="GVProducts_RowCommand">
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I have tried this however the row command does not get executed.